# Formik - Nested field validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have nested fields with number inputs and can't get the validation to work properly. Not sure if this is a problem with formik or yup / how the validation schema is declared but I'll start asking here.

In the example I have two fields which represents numbers and defaults to empty string. The validation works for the first fields but I can not get it to behave the same for the nested field. When I touch the field but don't type anything it returns :

> social.facebook must be a `number` type, but the final value was:
>   `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).

Example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-nested-schema-example-q4dlj?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems it's problem with formik , with nested field validation ! 
when it's number and value is initialized with empty string this last throw that error

you can workaround it by  transforming into null when it's an empty string , then set it as nullable inside validationSchema as below

```
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.number(),
    social: Yup.object().shape({
      facebook: Yup.number()
                   .transform((value, originalValue) => originalValue.trim() === "" ? null: value)
                   .nullable()
    })
})}
```

See [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-nested-schema-example-fpq84)

For further validation , if you want special message for only number add [.typeError("your message")](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtypeerrormessage-string-schema)

as below :

```
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.number().typeError("must be a number"),
    social: Yup.object().shape({
      facebook: Yup.number()
                   .typeError("must be a number")
                   .transform((value, originalValue) => originalValue.trim() === "" ? null: value)
                   .nullable()
    })
})}
```

PS: 
you can set initial values as , null for numbers and add .nullable() to schenma .